# Airbnb: is the service fee partially refunded after changing the dates of a long stay?

Tags: bookings, airbnb

Suppose that I make some long term reservation on airbnb from, say, Jan 1st to Dec 31st. Assume that there's no "special price" promotion involved. On June 1st I decide that I want to leave on October 1st, and I modifying my booking. My host accepts.

My understanding is that I will get full refund for the rent from October 2nd to Dec 31st, and that the cleaning fee won't be reimbursed. Will the airbnb service fee be reimbursed for the period October 2nd to Dec 31st?

Comment: You’ve said my answer isn’t enough. You can easily a) search for the answer yourself on the AirBnb website; and/or b) contact AirBnb Support to ask them.

Answer (score 1):

You won’t be charged in full upfront, so there’d be nothing to refund.

If you book a long term reservation that lasts 28 nights or more, you’ll be charged a first month down payment and the rest will be collected in monthly instalments, starting approximately one month after you check in. In the scenario you describe, your final monthly payment would be collected on 1 September.

https://www.airbnb.co.uk/help/article/245/how-do-i-pay-for-my-long-term-reservation

Answer (score 0):

I lost the authentication cookie; can someone turn this into a comment to traveller's answer pls?

The message by traveller is NOT answering my question. Suppose that the airbnb service fee for the period Jan 1st to Dec 31st is 500$. It seems that the total rent is split in non-equal payments each month. First off, it might be that the service fee is billed entirely in the first payment, therefore I will have already paid 500$ to airbnb regardless of any adjustment I make to the dates of my stay. Or, even if the service fee is split equally between the 12 payments, it might be that after adjusting the dates of my trip I will be required to still pay the "original" service fee for the 12 months' period of my initial reservation.

Comment: Hi, you can get both your accounts merged easily. See https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts for details.